# Interoperation between DroidVim and Termux

Tags: applications, storage, permissions

I've been using [DroidVim](https://github.com/shiftrot/droidvim) under Android for a few years now, primarily to edit a rather sprawling notes repository that I sync with my PC using `git` under [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=termux&so=1&c=apps).  The repo lives in a subdirectory of the internal storage root directory (`/storage/emulated/0/Notes`).  Under Android 8, which I'm still using on an older phone, I have DroidVim set to start up in that directory and I can load various session files for various tasks.  But under my newer phone, which runs Android 12, I can only see and access directories in internal storage (outside of the path allocated to DroidVim) and can't see any non-directory files (like, for example, the text files that I wish to edit with vim).

Is this because of changes to Android permissions?  If so, is there a way around it, with or without rooting the phone?

DroidVim now has a file browser built into it, and files you select to edit are copied over to a temporary location for editing.  This really doesn't work for my purposes.

There doesn't seem to be an option in DroidVim to enable more access to the filesystem.  Currently it looks like it has the "Files and media" permission; when I tap on that it shows a dialog with "Allow access to media only" selected; the only other option is "Don't allow".

I'm able to access files in the root of internal storage using other apps (like Termux, for example)—I just can't do that with DroidVim.  Termux cannot, however, access the "home" directory of DroidVim.  Is there another location I could store my repo where both DroidVim and Termux would have access to it?